# How to concatenate output from -o=custom-columns?

Tags: json, openshift

I'm trying to concatenating an output from oc get in openshift, I'm using -o=custom-columns but it's not joining 2 equal values ​​when I get the normal output...

```
{
    "roleRef":{
        "kind": "ClusterRole",
        "name": "view"
 }
}
```

The result I wanted is that in the same column the values ​​of "kind" and "name" come out like this:

```
ROLE
ClusterRole/view
```

If I give an "oc get rolebinding" in openshift it already gives me this return, but if I use -o=custom-columns to edit the columns as I prefer, I didn't find a way to convert this, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `kubectl`/`oc` only supports simplistic `jsonpath` expressions for `-o custom-columns`. If you *really* want to display this as a single column (as opposed to just displaying two separate columns), you'll have to rely on `-o jsonpath`. What this would look like:

```
$ oc get rolebinding -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.roleRef.kind}{"/"}{.roleRef.name}{"\n"}{end}'
```

It's obviously a bit more verbose, but infinitely more customizable. Hope this helps!

For what it's worth, if you want/need to get more fancy with column headers, etc, it would look something like

```
$ oc get rolebinding -o jsonpath='{"NAME"}{"\t"}{"ROLE"}{"\n"}{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.roleRef.kind}{"/"}{.roleRef.name}{"\n"}{end}'
```

Comment: HI!

Curious, because when we try the command "oc get rolebinding" without the "-o" it automatically returns these two concatenated fields, so I figured it would be possible to replicate this situation with the output of "custom-columns".

But thanks anyway for the help!

Comment: The output without `custom-columns` has the full go-template power behind the scenes. `custom-columns` is only meant to provide basic functionality, while allowing the other `-o` options to go even more complex if necessary. Honestly, 99% of the output I work with, I end up piping it into `jq` anyway, instead of relying the built-in display functionality. Please accept my answer if this solution works for you so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Sure, this make sense now rsrs thanks again :D